# If-statement error: "cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'"

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to display a Button called track with the text: "Start". But when I click the button I want to change the text to "Stop". Well, that's not much of a problem, but I want to change the text back in the "Start" when I press the button again. And over and over.

I already tried with an if-statement and using null, but that doesn't work. Also, the options when pressing alt+enter do not seem to work.

```
protected void change(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (track.Text == "Track")
{
    track.Text = "Track";
}
else
{
    track.Text = "Stop";
}
}
```

Comment: You need the comparison operator (`==`), which returns a `bool`, rather than the assignment operator (`=`), which returns the result of the assignment (a `string` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Should be `if (track.Text == "Start")`, not single `=`.

Comment: Oh shoot. I didn't notice you already answered :P I should refresh more.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do exactly what the errors says. Instead of `if (track.Text = "Start"` , it should be `if (track.Text == "Start")` :

```
protected void changetext(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (track.Text == "Start")
    {
        track.Text = "Start";
        status.Text = "Je staat stil";
    }
    else
    {
        track.Text = "Stop";
        status.Text = "Je bent in beweging. Ga zo door!";
    }
}
```

---

After OP's edit:

```
protected void change(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (track.Text == "Track")
    {
        track.Text = "Track";
    }
    else
    {
        track.Text = "Stop";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In other languages the test  `if (track.Text = "Start")` is nearly always a typo.

C# only allows `bool` for comparison, to virtually eliminate the risk of a typo leading to a bug.

The only possible mistake remaining is if you have something like this :

```
Bool a = true;
Bool b = false;
If(a = b){
  //this is true
}
```

Next time pay attention to that, you wan’t to compare two values, not the result of an affectation.